# In solr Master-Slave configuration custom indexes are getting out of sync sometimes in one of the slave server

Tags: solr, sitecore, solr4, solrnet, sitecore9

In our production environment, we have *Master-Slave* SOLR server configuration. We have 2 SOLR slave servers and configured SOLR load balancing URLs in prod *CM* and *CD* servers.
Right now we are facing intermittent issues with our custom indexes and our search is not working properly. So every time we face this intermittent issue we need to rebuild the custom indexes to get the search results.

After investigation, we found that custom indexes in one of the SOLR slave servers are getting out of sync sometimes with the master SOLR server.

Our custom indexes have primary and secondary cores which also point differently in master and slave servers as we are using **SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex**. Should we use SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex with Master-Slave configuration?

**Production Environment:**
For production, we have one Sitecore content management server and two content delivery servers.

Solr version: **7.2.1**

Sitecore version: **9.1.0**

Master Server `SolrConfig.xml`:
[image]

Slave Server `SolrConfig.xml`:

[image]

**Core.properties :**

***Master server:***

enable.master = true

enable.slave = false

***Slave server:***

enable. master = false

enable. slave = true

**SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex** config:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have any conditions that can result in an update being sent directly to your slave servers? I.e. that the index is being updated outside of what the master receives (for example deletes, etc.). Have you compared the sizes/hashes/dates of the replicated files on the slave to what is available on the master? Does a proper sync happen if you issue an optimize on the master? (i.e. to get all segments to be rewritten).

Comment: Mostly the custom indexes size/dates/document number/version in slave server are same as Master. As this issue is an intermittent so sizes/dates/doc number gets different when indexes are out of sync.

Comment: @MatsLindh We are using single load balancing URL (using round robin algo and includes all three master/slave servers) in both CM and CD servers so it there any possibility the indexes can be updated in Slave server instead of master? We are also rebuilding the custom indexes programmatically using a task schedular.

Comment: If you're also _indexing_ against the load balancing url, then yes - if you're not using SolrCloud, the updates will be issued against the server that receives the request (in cloud mode everything is handled transparently for you, so the request is forwarded to the correct nodes). Index against the master url, use the load balanced url for querying.

Comment: @MatsLindh We are not using the SolrCloud. Only in connection string config we have configured the solr load balancing URL and have done setup in solr index cores for master slave configuration and replicating the indexes in slave server. So, you are saying in such configuration there is a chance slave server indexes can be updated instead of master? Can you explain me more on this how it is possible??

Comment: If you're sending your request to _the load balancer_, the load balancer will do just that - it'll balance every request across the available servers. In that case, only 1/n requests will go to the master node, while the other go to one of your replicated indexes. Update requests should _only go to the master node_, and not be load balanced in any way.

Comment: Thank you so much @MatsLindh, appreciate your help.  Should I use SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex for custom primary and secondary indexes in master-slave configuration as shown in the above screenshot. And do I need to change anything in my IndexUpdateStrategy?

Comment: I have no experience with sitecore what-so-ever, so I can't say anything about sitecore configuration.